# How to create a Named Constant Array for Use in Data Validation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a list in the excel name manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>) which I can use to create drop down menues to allow users to select predefined values in specific cells. This list should be constant and not depend on ranges in a sheet. 
If I try the approach I used to create constants for simple numbers (i.e. putting the value in the reference field) I fail. Is it simply not possible to create lists with the name manager or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you are not actually looking for an option to give a static list a name but you want to limit the drop-down options to a static list.

Given that's correct you don't need the name manager to achieve what you want. You can limit the accepted values for the cell to a static list using the data validation feature itself. You just need to enter the values, themselves, in the `Source` field of the dialog box instead of a range or named range:

```
Yes,No,I do not know
```

Please pay attention if you are using a german version of Excel like I do. You need to replace the `,` with `;` (I don't know about other local versions):

```
Ja;Nein;Weiß ich nicht
```

See the [Microsoft Office help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-manage-drop-down-lists-28db87b6-725f-49d7-9b29-ab4bc56cefc2) for detailed instructions and see my screenshot here:

[image: The Source field of the Dialog with Example]

**EDIT**:
Taking your comment into account what you want seems to be impossible. See the posts by the MVP in the [Microsoft Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/data-validation-named-range-returning-array/bdb44056-700b-413e-9333-bf1942ac2f2c). You actually can [assign a name to a constant array](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Name-an-array-constant-69431fa5-9bed-4612-950b-25e898b265f5) but this will not work with the data validation feature.

Comment: The result looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ej9vH.png) then. (Could not add the link to my answer due to missing rep.)

Comment: I know this way define static lists. However, it is not exactly what I am looking for. I generally have a larger number of sheets in which I want to use exactly the same list. Therefore, it is not convenient to newly define this for the respective ranges in all sheets. That is the reason why I am looking for one single list which I can access via a name in all sheets.

Comment: Please see my edit; Links: [`[3]`](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/data-validation-named-range-returning-array/bdb44056-700b-413e-9333-bf1942ac2f2c) [`[4]`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Name-an-array-constant-69431fa5-9bed-4612-950b-25e898b265f5)

Comment: If you google for `excel datavalidation source constant array` you will find many unanswered forum questions asking exactly what you asked, which makes me sure the MVP is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a special sheet to hold the list of values. Type the values, one list item in each cell. Assign this range of cells a name by selecting the cells, then press [Ctrl] + [F3] and click New to create a new name (or use any other proper method for assigning a name to a range of cells). Then, for whichever cells you want to limit entry to items in the list, set data validation to type list and as the source type or paste an equals sign and the name you gave to the cells. The range of cells must be one contiguous region. When you make changes to the list by editing cells in the named range or adjusting the bounds of the range, those changes will immediately propagate to the cells whose validation use the named range as a source. You can hide or protect the worksheet if you don't want users to be able to see or modify the worksheet containing the list.

Comment: Please show with more specificity